# Stream file uploaded with Express.js through formidable and gm to eliminate double write

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphicsmagick

I want to upload and resize an image in one go without writing to disk twice.

To upload the image I use: **node-formidable**: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

To resize the image I use: **gm**: http://aheckmann.github.com/gm/

When I run this code I get an error: 'This socket is closed'.

> Error: spawn ENOENT
>       at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)

My code:

```
function uploadPhotos (req, res) {
  // parse a file upload
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.multiples = true;      // Allow multiple files with HTML5 multiple attribute.
  form.maxFields = 100;       // Maximum number of fields (no files).
  form.keepExtensions = true; // Include the extensions of the original files.
  form.uploadDir = ORIGINAL_IMAGES_DIR;

  form.onPart = function (part) {

    if (!part.filename) {
      // Let formidable handle all non-file parts.
      return this.handlePart(part);
    }

    gm(part)
    .resize(200, 200)
    .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(RESIZED_IMAGES_DIR, 'resized_' + part.filename)));
      stdout.on('end', function () {
        res.send(200);
      });
    });
  };

  form.parse(req);
}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.
A similar problem can be found here: [Stream file uploaded with Express.js through gm to eliminate double write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764585/stream-file-uploaded-with-express-js-through-gm-to-eliminate-double-write/11801289#11801289)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought npm install would do the trick but it didn't install GraphicsMagick.
Installing GraphicsMagick manually solved my problem.

Thanks to tuck:
[gm stream stdout pipe throwing unhandled error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893645/gm-stream-stdout-pipe-throwing-unhandled-error?rq=1)